# How to Install RoundCube on Debian for Virtual Users?

Tags: debian, webmail

I got a Droplet (server) from Digital Ocean running Debian Jessie 8.2. And the following were installed:

- [Apache2](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/perfect-server-debian-8-jessie-apache-bind-dovecot-ispconfig-3/2/),
- [MariaDB](http://Apache2),
- [phpMyAdmin](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-debian-7),
- and PHP5 were installed.

The server is [serving two domains](http://dimitris.apeiro.gr/2015/03/31/how-to-setup-maildir-style-virtual-mailboxes-in-debian-with-postfix/) `example1.com` and `example2.com`. I have configured virtual users for those domains and when I send mail to `info@example.com`, I can see it in `/home/vmail/example1.com/info/new`

I have read the [HowToForge](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/roundcube-installation-on-debian-8-jessie/) tutorial on how to download, install, and configure RoundCube on Debian. But aside of installing the application, they require to tie it to `MySQL` and `ISPConfig 3`. Is it required to tie RoundCube to MySQL? Also, what is the correct way to install and configure RoundCube to work with Virtual Users (the current setup I have)?

Lastly, is there a better webmail application that is easier/simpler to configure for virtual users?